# Correct way to import node modules in node webkit

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-webkit

I am developing a node web kit application and want to import node modules in my project. My main page is index.html.

In index.html, I have included the file which contains my main node logic.

In app.js however if I include any module, using  `var cheerio  = require("cheerio");` it says module not found. This is because, index.html is in my working directory, where as when I run the code, the current working directory changes to some temp folder in `C:` Drive. How do I include my required files in `app.js`? All my node modules are in a folder called node_modules

The folder directory structure is as below:

```
node_modules
           \cheerio
package.json
index.html
app.js
```

Comment: did you packaged your app into .exe file?

Comment: please post your config file, and show how do you launching the `app.js`